# Freemarker boolean attribute retrieval

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, freemarker

I have a Customer object which has a boolean attribute letterActivated. The getter method goes as below as per the standard java practices.

```
public Boolean isLetterActivated() {
    return letterActivated;
}
```

But seems like Freemaker doesn't pickup `customer.letterActivated` expression and i guess it might be cause of i don't have getLetterActivated method. (Note that other expressions of customer object works fine which all have get*** methods).

How should i reference this boolean variable from FTL? Note that i'm unable to change the getter method name (isMobileBillingAccount) as it is in existing code and referred in many places. Also it is the correct way for a boolean getter i guess.

Comment: if you are using an IDE such as eclipse you can refactor the method to `getXXX` which will change all the instance of the method call. a boolean getter can be named with a suffix as `is` as well as `get`.

Comment: :) I know the IDE will refactor with references, but it is in a client jar which i'm not supposed to touch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use `public boolean isLetterActivated()` or `public Boolean getLetterActivated()`. The `Boolean` + `is` combination doesn't define a JavaBean property according the JavaBeans specification. You don't have to change the name, you can just add the correct getter. Or as a last chance, you can use `customer.isLetterActivated()` in FTL.

Answer (score 1):

a boolean getter can be name `getXXX` also.. and as you said there are other references refering with the existing method `isLetterActivated`. i would suggest doing this since the other references are out of scope to you.

```
public boolean getLetterActivated() {
    return this.isLetterActivated();
}
```

This way you dont mess up the existing code and the new code can use the new method... but i think this is a bad design. but given the circumstance i would advice you to go for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
${customer.letterActivated?c}
```

Uses `isLetterActivated()` and 
Display "true" if the value is `true`.

Following code also function without any problem for me (**tested in freemarker 2.3.20**)

```
<#if (customer.letterActivated)!false>
 Great letter is activated! ${customer.letterActivated?c} man
<#/if>
```

`()!false` part is only there to handle `null` values.

Even more information from freemarker compiler:

> ## Freemarker Compiler output
>
> Can't convert boolean to string automatically, because the "boolean_format" setting was "true,false", which is the legacy default computer-language format, and hence isn't accepted.
>
> Tip: If you just want "true"/"false" result as you are generting computer-language output, use "?c", like ${myBool?c}.
>
> Tip: You can write myBool?string('yes', 'no') and like to specify boolean formatting in place.
>
> Tip: If you need the same two values on most places, the programmers should set the "boolean_format" setting to something like "yes,no".

Comment: In your customer class, do u have only isLetterActivated as the getter for letterActivated boolean attribute? or else, do u have getLetterActivated too? I tried customer.letterActivated?c but didn't work...

Comment: It seems customer.letterActivated?c only works for Freemarker 2.3.20 and later versions. Older versions could use customer.letterActivated?string('yes', 'no') instead. And no I don't have getLetterActivated() method. letterActivated field is also not required, or could be private. but not tested in older versions.